# R assigning variables in for loop

Tags: r

I'm working in R with a for-loop, to create new vectors. 'files' contains multiple data frames with more or less 500 rows.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*txt")
files = lapply(temp, read.delim) 

pos = c(1:100)
results = null

for (i in pos) {
    nameA = paste("A", i, sep = "_")
    nameC = paste("C", i, sep = "_")
    resA = assign(nameA, unlist(lapply(files, function(x) x$perA[x$position==i])))
    resC = assign(nameC, unlist(lapply(files, function(x) x$perC[x$position==i])))
    cbind(summary(resA), results) #incorrect
    cbind(summary(resC), results) #incorrect
}
```

now I want to perform 'summary' on resA & resC for all values in 'pos'. I want to put those results in 1 dataframe (results). How can I do that now?

Comment: so basically 200 columns - 100 each for namesA and namesC pos 1 to 100 right?

Comment: use `cbind()` in each iteration of `for` loop

Comment: @joel.wilson: to answer your first question: indeed. The second comment: OK, but I cannot just do 'sum = summary(nameA) inside the for loop for example.

Comment: first have result of `unlist(lapply(files, function(x) x$perA[x$position==i]))` in a vector `x`. take its summary , `cbind(x)` and then `assign` original `x` to nameA

Comment: @Parfait even if both vectors are of uneven length, summary will return a 5 element vector right. So that need not be a worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat along these lines :

```
# create a data.frame with 6 rows( since summary() returns a vector of 6 elements
df <- data.frame(1:6)
# set the rownames of df
rownames(df) = names(summary(1:6))  

for (i in pos) {
    nameA = paste("A", i, sep = "_")
    ...
    xA = unlist(lapply(files, function(x) x$perA[x$position==i]))
    xC = unlist(lapply(files, function(x) x$perC[x$position==i]))
    df = cbind(df, as.numeric(summary(xA)), as.numeric(summary(xC))) 
    assign(nameA, xA)
    assign(nameC, xC)
}

# set the column names of df
df[1] = NULL # initial column removed 
colnames(df) = c("id", paste0("summary",c("A","C"), rep(1:100, each = 2)))
```

Comment: does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to save each vector on its own and not inside a list? This would make further analysis easier.

We can still combine your vectors into a single list with `mget`. Then apply the `summary` function to this list and use `cbind()` to combine results into a single matrix.

```
list_A <- mget(ls(pattern="A_[0-9]"))
list_C <- mget(ls(pattern="C_[0-9]"))
summary_A <- do.call(cbind,lapply(list_A,summary))
summary_C <- do.call(cbind,lapply(list_C,summary))
summary_All <- data.frame(summary_A, summary_C)
```

Of course you have to be careful whether you have other objects with the same naming pattern in your environment.